# Does graph.microsoft.com have documented ip ranges from which it sends push notifications?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Does graph.microsoft.com have ip ranges from which it sends push notifications?

I'm trying to start using subscription to push notification, but for security purposes we need to specify the range of ips for external services which can access our test environment. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 1):

The list of IP addresses is referenced in the documentation under [Firewall Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#firewall-configuration):

> You can optionally configure the firewall that protects your notification URL to allow inbound connections only from Microsoft Graph. This allows you to reduce further exposure to invalid change notifications that are sent to your notification URL. These invalid change notifications can be trying to trigger the custom logic that you implemented. For a complete list of IP addresses used by Microsoft Graph to deliver change notifications, [see additional endpoints for Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/additional-office365-ip-addresses-and-urls).
>
> Note: The listed IP addresses that are used to deliver change notifications can be updated at any time without notice.